# maps displayed wrong on mobile (using JQuery mobile)

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery mobile and I have to display some maps.
I'm using a function that create maps every time that I click on the specific link but after the generation of the first map, the others are displayed wrong.

Here an example,
First map:

[image: First Map]

Other maps:

[image: Second Map]

I use a function like this:

```
function buildMap(div){

    var coord = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    var options = {
        zoom: 13,
        scrollwheel: false,
        scaleControl: true,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        center: coord,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(div, options);

    return map;
}
```

Can you help me?

Thank you!!

Comment: Related: http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-mobile-example.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved, you need to create the map on the "pageshow" event (an event of jQuery mobile):

```
$('#map_page').live('pageshow',function(event, ui){
    buildResultMap('#map_canvas');
});
```

Comment: nice solution, I actually modified for my needs like this and it works just as well:
`$(document).live('pageshow',function(event, ui){
  initialize_map_with_properties();
});`

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to trigger the resize event OR not to use Ajax. Phill has guided you to an example how it's done with the [jQuery Mobile Google maps plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map)  which uses Ajax (and calls $('#map_canvas').gmap('refresh'); on pageload. The plugin is very easy to use (especially if you already know Google maps syntax).

Comment: No, nothing...

I tried to rewrite the functions and I added this "google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize');" but nothing happen.

However I noticed that this problem happen only on android devices/chrome/safari, on iphone/ipad all works right. I also noticed that, after map load, if I zoom the page in the browser or in the android device (with pinch zoom), the map fix itself.

Comment: Should work if you resize on pageshow. But creating the map on pageshow works as well.

Comment: Yes, now I create the map on pageshow and it works as well... thanks!!

Comment: I added some alternative solutions in the WIKI: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/wiki/jquery_ui_map_v_3_tutorial#Help,_my_map_is_rendered_incorrectly!_(jQM)