# google maps displayed wrong on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile

This is a follow-up question to the Mark Design question. 
[maps displayed wrong on mobile (using JQuery mobile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089882/maps-displayed-wrong-on-mobile-using-jquery-mobile?rq=1) 
I am new to javascript and jquery and could not apply the solutions provided in answers to Mark Design question in above link to my own google map script. 
I am doing much the same thing Mark Design did with this file: 
http://skool411.info/m/Hawaii-2.html 
On mobile devices, the maps don't display correctly and do the same thing as shown in the pictures Mark Design posted above. Can someone here please show me how to apply 'pageshow' and 'resize' ? I also tried to turn off ajax and that did not work for me: 
http://skool411.info/m/Hawaii-1.html 
It's most likely that I don't know how to do that correctly. If someone can show me how to turn off ajax that would be great also. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You might consider the [Static Map API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/), only because a single image is much more bandwidth-friendly. I do this in my mobile sites and link the image directly to Google Maps.

Comment: Bandwidth is not an issue, we hardly have any visitor to the site, it's more about learning and we would like the few visitors we have being able to explore the locations we post if they want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some errors in `calcRoute()` because you don't have `directionsService` on this context.

First, let's put `map` and `Loc1` on "global" context:

```
var map;
var Loc1;
```

Using the solution of suggested question, need create the map when page is shown:

```
$('#mapPage').live('pageshow',
        function(event, ui) {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom : 7,
                mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                center : Loc1
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
                    mapOptions);
        });
```

Initialize function:

```
function initialize(Hlat1, Hlng1, Hlat2, Hlng2) {
    Loc1 = new google.maps.LatLng(Hlat1, Hlng1);

    var $content = $("#mapPage div:jqmData(role=content)");
    $content.height(screen.height);
    $.mobile.changePage($("#mapPage"));

    calcRoute(Hlat1, Hlng1, Hlat2, Hlng2);
}
```

And finally, calculate route:

```
function calcRoute(Hlat1, Hlng1, Hlat2, Hlng2) {
    var rendererOptions = {
        draggable : true
    };
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    var request = {
        origin : new google.maps.LatLng(Hlat1, Hlng1),
        destination : new google.maps.LatLng(Hlat2, Hlng2),
        travelMode : google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        }
    });
}
```

**[Here](http://pastebin.com/RDKtiS7N)** is the complete code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, Paulo. I replaced our js with yours and it works great.